# ¿Cómo generar doble cabecera en un datagridview en visual basic.net?

Tags: vb.net

[image: Mas o menos así]

Solo eh escuchado del método pain o paint (no me recuerdo bien del nombre) pero no entiendo muy bien ese método, eh visto el codigo pero no logro comprenderlo, no está bien explicado, ayuda porfavor.

Comment: que fue lo que viste de ese metodo que no entendiste? probaste algo? esto es winforms o wpf? por favor mira [ask]

Comment: @gbianchi Pues casi todo, es que no explican que parte es la del metodo y para que sirve cada declaración y comandos.

Comment: como que parte es la del metodo? que fue lo que leiste?